# MySql Admin User lost Privileges

Tags: azure, mysqladmin, azure-mysql-database, mysqladministrator

On PreProd - MySqlServer Admin account lost the privileges which was all good yesterday.

When ran `show grants for xxxxxadmin;`on Dev its resulted as

[image]

On Pre-Prod (which was same as Dev)

[image]

There is no other admin account to log into the server.  Is there a way to get the Privileges back.

These are Azure MySql databases.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure Portal you can reset the password.

Navigate to your Azure MySql database in Azure Portal and in `Overivew`, and click`Reset Password`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-create-manage-server-portal#update-admin-password